# Using 'cifs' to connect to windows share

Tags: linux

I am working with UBUNTU 12.04, and am trying to connect to a windows share (SBS2008r2).

If i use the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //domain/share /media/files -o credentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials
```

my folder gets mounted correctly.

However, when i try to make this mount automatically by adding the following line in the /etc/fstab:

```
//domain/share /media/files cifs credentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

and then run the command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get the following error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

What am i missing?

**EDIT**:

After playing around, i found that the following in *fstab* works:

```
//domain/share /media/files cifs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials,umask=777 0 0
```

Comment: Your fstab example is missing the filesystem field, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example taken from ubuntu page [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) (Adjusted to your sample):

```
//domain/share /media/files cifs credentials=/home/linux/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

But yes as grawity has commented, the 'filesystem' (in this case cifs) is missing from your fstab. And also lack of spacing (which could be a typo on the forum which hopefully not in your fstab)

Comment: Sorry, @Darius it was a typo